User & hostname suddenly changed after update, now sudo and internet issues
Ubuntu 24.04.01 LTS
Upgraded from 22.04.01
Dell precision 7550
Notification received to upgrade and did so.
It said some things were partially upgraded, but everything was working normally for a day.
updated firmware. everything seemed fine.
Suddenly couldn’t connect to internet - suspect this is connected.to the vpn and this happened before with proton.
Visited terminal and noticed username and host name different. Username has changed by one letter and now the host name says 127 as opposed to what it should be. This is the only account on the device and is administrator.
Sudo command output:
Sudo: unable to resolve host 127.0.01localhost :Temporary failure in name resolution

Used the command:
Code:
 hostnamectl

Pretty hostname shows my old, correct, username and hostname.
Static hostname has no space between ip and localhost.
An hour later internet and sudo commands worked again.
Now the sudo command outputs the same error output as listed above, but then it will execute the command successfully anyway. Internet won't work again.
Tried:
sudo -l

Output:
Matching Defaults entries for <My incorrect username> on 127:
env_reset,
mail_badpass,
secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin\:/snap/bin, use_pty
User <My incorrect username> may run the following commands on 127:
(ALL: ALL) ALL


can't speak to the 24.04 upgrade issues but 127.0.01localhost is a mangled version of what I'd expect to see in /etc/hosts (should be 127.0.0.1    localhost)

Visited terminal and noticed username and host name different. - where/how do see this? as part of the PS1/prompt? title bar of the terminal? output from some command(s)?

For example, in terminal if my original username was rob@dellprecision, after the upgrade it became rod@127. In case this isn't clear, I'm referring to the prompt that appears before each command that is type. @markp-fuso

"It said some things were partially upgraded"
Let's be clear: A partial upgrade means the release-upgrade FAILED.
A partial upgrade is like sitting in a lifeboat. You cannot travel far on a partially-upgraded system. It will not withstand a storm. Your system must be repaired or reinstalled.
The problems you are encountering suggest reinstalling.
Use the system, working as it is, to prepare a new 24.04 LiveUSB installer, and to backup your data to some other media. Then reinstall Ubuntu.
If your system is too hard to use (like no internet), then use a different machine to create the LiveUSB. Boot into the LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment, and use that environment to preserve your data. Then reinstall.
The most frequent cause of partial upgrades are package conflicts caused by non-Ubuntu deb packages. Often an older LTS system gets newer PPA or other non-Ubuntu packages bolted on, and those newer packages cause the conflicts. There are other possibilites.

Thanks. I was trying to avoid that as I don't have that OS on live USB and can't access the internet, but it seems that's the only way. @user535733
